# In kubernetes DNS queries fail between nodes

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes, kubeadm

I have an issue with kubernetes and coreDNS that I am not able to solve.

System information

- 1 master + 2 workers
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 9.3 (Plow)
- k8s: v1.28.7
- flannel: v0.24.2
- coreDNS: v1.10.1
- kubeadm used to create cluster
- no firewalls
- firewalld & SELinux disabled

```bash
NAMESPACE      NAME                                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS       AGE     IP              NODE
default        dnsutils                                           1/1     Running   78 (51m ago)   3d6h    10.244.1.9      worker2
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-6qkt4                              1/1     Running   0              172m    10.229.144.10   master
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-jqhql                              1/1     Running   0              172m    10.229.144.12   worker2
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-qzw5c                              1/1     Running   0              172m    10.229.144.11   worker1
kube-system    coredns-565799df8b-7nncc                           1/1     Running   1 (3h7m ago)   3d7h    10.244.1.8      worker2
kube-system    coredns-565799df8b-mcwff                           1/1     Running   1 (3h8m ago)   3d7h    10.244.2.8      worker1
kube-system    etcd-master                                        1/1     Running   5 (3h8m ago)   3h13m   10.229.144.10   master
kube-system    kube-apiserver-master                              1/1     Running   1 (3h8m ago)   4d3h    10.229.144.10   master
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-master                     1/1     Running   1 (3h8m ago)   4d3h    10.229.144.10   master
kube-system    kube-proxy-4lbsp                                   1/1     Running   1 (3h7m ago)   3h12m   10.229.144.12   worker2
kube-system    kube-proxy-6m4l4                                   1/1     Running   1 (3h8m ago)   3h12m   10.229.144.10   master
kube-system    kube-proxy-r9zgx                                   1/1     Running   1 (3h8m ago)   3h12m   10.229.144.11   worker1
kube-system    kube-scheduler-master                              1/1     Running   1 (3h8m ago)   4d3h    10.229.144.10   master
```

Problem is that dns queries fail if sent from one worker to another. To demonstrate this I have dnsutils pod running on worker2. If I query a name from coredns on the same worker:

```bash
[jenkins@nordlabkubem ~]$ kubectl exec -it dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.96.0.1
```

It works fine. But if I point the query to coredns on worker1:

```bash
[jenkins@nordlabkubem ~]$ kubectl exec -it dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes 10.244.2.8
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

command terminated with exit code 1
```

The `/etc/resolv.conf` is in order:

```bash
[user@master ~]$ kubectl exec -it dnsutils -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local mylab.local
nameserver 10.96.0.10
options ndots:5
```

I've been tracing this problem a while now. If I `tcpdump` interfaces on both workers while doing `nslookup` on dnsutils (on worker2) to coredns on worker1 I do not see incoming traffic on worker1:

```bash
[user@worker2 ~]$ sudo tcpdump -nn udp port 8472
13:58:13.330215 IP <worker2>.54673 > <worker1>.8472: OTV, flags [I] (0x08), overlay 0, instance 1
IP 10.244.1.9.56384 > 10.244.2.8.53: 50759+ A? kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. (54)
13:58:18.330300 IP <worker2>.54673 > <worker1>.8472: OTV, flags [I] (0x08), overlay 0, instance 1
IP 10.244.1.9.56384 > 10.244.2.8.53: 50759+ A? kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. (54)
13:58:23.330377 IP <worker2>.54673 > <worker1>.8472: OTV, flags [I] (0x08), overlay 0, instance 1
IP 10.244.1.9.56384 > 10.244.2.8.53: 50759+ A? kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. (54)

[user@worker1 ~]$ sudo tcpdump -nn udp port 8472
# nothing here
```

If I ping, then I see traffic incoming:

```bash
[user@master ~]$ kubectl exec -it dnsutils -- ping 10.244.2.8
PING 10.244.2.8 (10.244.2.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.244.2.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=0.956 ms


#worker2
14:17:25.308459 IP <worker2>.47186 > <worker1>.8472: OTV, flags [I] (0x08), overlay 0, instance 1
IP 10.244.1.9 > 10.244.2.8: ICMP echo request, id 98, seq 1, length 64
14:17:25.309282 IP <worker1>.48946 > <worker2>.8472: OTV, flags [I] (0x08), overlay 0, instance 1
IP 10.244.2.8 > 10.244.1.9: ICMP echo reply, id 98, seq 1, length 64

#worker1
14:17:25.308827 IP <worker2>.47186 > <worker1>.8472: OTV, flags [I] (0x08), overlay 0, instance 1
IP 10.244.1.9 > 10.244.2.8: ICMP echo request, id 98, seq 1, length 64
14:17:25.308927 IP <worker1>.48946 > <worker2>.8472: OTV, flags [I] (0x08), overlay 0, instance 1
IP 10.244.2.8 > 10.244.1.9: ICMP echo reply, id 98, seq 1, length 64
```

kube-proxy logging is increase but showing no erros. No errors in flannel logs. No errors in coredns logs, but I do not know how to increase logging there.

Coredns cm:

```bash
$ kubectl get cm -n kube-system coredns -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        log
        errors
        health {
           lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
           max_concurrent 1000
        }
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
```

kube-flannel-cfg:

```bash
$ kubectl get cm -n kube-flannel kube-flannel-cfg -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  cni-conf.json: |
    {
      "name": "cbr0",
      "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
      "plugins": [
        {
          "type": "flannel",
          "delegate": {
            "hairpinMode": true,
            "isDefaultGateway": true
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "portmap",
          "capabilities": {
            "portMappings": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  net-conf.json: |
    {
      "Network": "10.244.0.0/16",
      "Backend": {
        "Type": "vxlan"
      }
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"cni-conf.json":"{\n  \"name\": \"cbr0\",\n  \"cniVersion\": \"0.3.1\",\n  \"plugins\": [\n    {\n      \"type\": \"flannel\",\n      \"delegate\": {\n        \"hairpinMode\": true,\n        \"isDefaultGateway\": true\n      }\n    },\n    {\n      \"type\": \"portmap\",\n      \"capabilities\": {\n        \"portMappings\": true\n      }\n    }\n  ]\n}\n","net-conf.json":"{\n  \"Network\": \"10.244.0.0/16\",\n  \"Backend\": {\n    \"Type\": \"vxlan\"\n  }\n}\n"},"kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"flannel","k8s-app":"flannel","tier":"node"},"name":"kube-flannel-cfg","namespace":"kube-flannel"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2024-03-11T11:47:42Z"
  labels:
    app: flannel
    k8s-app: flannel
    tier: node
  name: kube-flannel-cfg
  namespace: kube-flannel
  resourceVersion: "524202"
  uid: 036330ff-62aa-4bf8-8066-f9e5d7314869
```

I am thinking that networking is fine, but there is some odd problem with coredns?

The problem is also there if any of the pods is running on master.

I have rebooted pods, servers, reinstalled flannel and so on but I just can't get this to work. Otherwise cluster seems to work ok - pods are running and no errors in logs.

Comment: The connection seems to be fine:

```
dnstools# nc -uvzw2 10.244.1.10 53
10.244.1.10 (10.244.1.10:53) open
    
dnstools# nc -uvzw2 10.244.2.10 53
10.244.2.10 (10.244.2.10:53) open
```

- dnstools running on worker1
- 10.244.1.10 = coredns on worker2
- 10.244.2.10 = coredns on worker1

Answer (score 1):

Problem got solved with steps listed in  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/72370#issuecomment-1647206933:

```
$ sudo ethtool -K ens192 tx-checksum-ip-generic off
$ sudo nmcli con modify ens192 ethtool.feature-tx-checksum-ip-generic off
```

I failed to mention that servers are running on top of VMWare.